# SQLAlchemy Python Select Order By

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlalchemy for my python script, and I am unable to order the select query in descending order according to a column.

This is my code

```
    query_limit = 500
    select_query = tbl_stack.select().order_by('id desc').limit(query_limit)
    for row in con.execute(select_query):
      ...
```

However this gives me the following error

> Can't resolve label reference 'id desc'; converting to text() (this
>   warning may be suppressed after 10 occurrences)
>   util.ellipses_string(element.element))

How can I order the select query in descending order in sqlalchemy?

Comment: Hi @rksh, you should try that `order_by(desc(table.colname))`

Comment: @AndyK hey, i tried it gives the following error ```NameError: global name 'desc' is not defined```

Comment: have you try to import the desc before? `from sqlalchemy import desc`

Comment: thanks @AndyK it's working now

Comment: good I was able to help @rksh